# Dreamweaver - Loop a FLV video

Tags: html, object, video, flv

as the title explains, I want my FLV video in loaded via dreamweaver, once it finishes, it should start again from the beginning aka looping. How would I do that?

Here is my code:

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="800" height="280" id="FLVPlayer">
  <param name="movie" value="FLVPlayer_Progressive.swf" />
  <param name="quality" value="high" />
  <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
  <param name="scale" value="noscale" />
  <param name="salign" value="lt" />
  <param name="FlashVars" value="&amp;MM_ComponentVersion=1&amp;skinName=Clear_Skin_1&amp;streamName=includes/anim&amp;autoPlay=true&amp;autoRewind=true" />
  <param name="swfversion" value="8,0,0,0" />
  <!-- This param tag prompts users with Flash Player 6.0 r65 and higher to download the latest version of Flash Player. Delete it if you don’t want users to see the prompt. -->
  <param name="expressinstall" value="Scripts/expressInstall.swf" />
  <!-- Next object tag is for non-IE browsers. So hide it from IE using IECC. -->
  <!--[if !IE]>-->
  <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="FLVPlayer_Progressive.swf" width="800" height="280">
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
    <param name="scale" value="noscale" />
    <param name="loop" value="true"> 
    <param name="salign" value="lt" />
    <param name="FlashVars" value="&amp;MM_ComponentVersion=1&amp;skinName=Clear_Skin_1&amp;streamName=includes/anim&amp;autoPlay=true&amp;autoRewind=true" />
    <param name="swfversion" value="8,0,0,0" />
    <param name="expressinstall" value="Scripts/expressInstall.swf" />
    <!-- The browser displays the following alternative content for users with Flash Player 6.0 and older. -->
    <div>
      <h4>Content on this page requires a newer version of Adobe Flash Player.</h4>
      <p><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"><img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" /></a></p>
    </div>
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
  </object>
  <!--<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Dreamweaver's default player, I would experiment using autoPlay/autoRewind/loop, but not all together. I googled around and they all say that what you have should work.

Answer (score 1):

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
AC_FL_RunContent( 'codebase','http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7,0,0,0','width','495','height','373','id','FLVPlayer','src','FLVPlayer_Progressive','flashvars','&MM_ComponentVersion=1&skinName=Clear_Skin_1&streamName=ght&autoPlay=true&autoRewind=true&loop=true','quality','high','scale','noscale','name','FLVPlayer','salign','lt','pluginspage','http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/download.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash','movie','FLVPlayer_Progressive','wmode','opaque','loop','true' ); //end AC code
    </script>
  <noscript>
  <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7,0,0,0" width="495" height="373" id="FLVPlayer">
    <param name="movie" value="FLVPlayer_Progressive.swf" />
    <param name="salign" value="lt" />
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <param name="scale" value="noscale" />
    <param name="FlashVars" value="&MM_ComponentVersion=1&skinName=Clear_Skin_1&streamName=ght&autoPlay=true&autoRewind=true&loop=true" />
    <embed src="FLVPlayer_Progressive.swf" flashvars="&MM_ComponentVersion=1&skinName=Clear_Skin_1&streamName=ght&autoPlay=true&autoRewind=true" quality="high" scale="noscale" width="495" height="373" name="FLVPlayer" salign="LT" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/download.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash" />  
</object>
  </noscript>
```